# Is there any mechanism in kafka that will reject message if the message has the key , but their is a already message in the kafka with same key?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Is there any mechanism in kafka that will reject message if the message has the key , but their is a already message in the kafka with same key ?

Answer (score 1):

No; there is not; Kafka just maintains a linear log of records.